# dragging DIVs to horizontal sortable container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm building some sort of a playlist creator. I have some items the user can choose from and a horizontal sortable timeline area to drop those items on.

The Draggable:

```
$(".Name:not(#Add a .Name)").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(){
        $('#MainPage').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
        $(".Name").css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
    },
//          helper: "clone",
    helper: function() { 
        return $("<div class='"+$(this).parent().attr('class')+"' id='"+$(this).parent().attr('id')+"'><div class='"+$(this).attr("class")+"' id='"+$(this).attr("id")+"'>"+ $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1] +"</div></div>"); 
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('#MainPage').css('cursor', 'auto');
        $(".Name").css('cursor', '-moz-grab');
    },
    connectToSortable: "#TimelineDrop",
    appendTo: '#MainPage',
    containment: 'DOM',
    zIndex: 800,
    addClasses: false
});
```

The Sortable:

```
$("#TimelineDrop").sortable({ 
    over: function(event, ui) {
        var Breite = ((TimeSpace*5)/(TimeSpace/(currentspacing+24)))-2;
        $("#TimelineDrop").append("<div class='TimelineMarker' style='width:"+ Breite +"px;'>\u00A0</div>");
    },
    receive: function(event, ui) { 
        dropped=true;
        AddElementToTimeline($(this), event, ui, dropped); 
    },
    start: function( event, ui ){ 
        $('#MainPage').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
        $('.TimelineElement').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing');
        drag=true;
    },
    axis: "x",
    stop: function( event, ui ){
        $('#MainPage').css('cursor', 'auto');
        $('.TimelineElement').css('cursor', '-moz-grab');
        database.updateElementPosition($('.TimelineElement').index($(ui.item)), $(ui.item).children('.TimelineElementTitle').attr('id').split('D')[1], GET('id'));
        drag=false;
    }
});
```

I tried all kinds of different stuff but can't get it to work propperly. What would like to be able to is drag items from the available area to the timeline und drop them between allready appended ones. So far the helper allways get appended (vertically) above the existing elements and when I drop it the final element get append at the very last position. I hope It's clear what I'm trying to archive...

I have a fiddle right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5SBax/4/

I want the marker to be displayed where the element will be added (between others). And I need to get rid of the helper element which also get added every time...

Comment: Please provide a working http://www.jsfiddle.net with your code

Comment: Added it. Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: sorry, the one above is wrong... here's the right one: http://jsfiddle.net/5SBax/4/

Comment: Still not very clear. Are the Green should be stuck with the brown ones? Because now you can separate them

Comment: Its a small thing. If you provide your question clearly , surely you will get answer.

Comment: I want to get rid of the green ones in the sortable timeline. They should only be displayed as a helper while dragging. Appended to the sortable should only be the brown ones at the position that I choose and not allways at the very end. Also I want the Marker that I show during dragging to be, where the future elment should be It also gets append to the very end of the line. Sorry for the missunderstandings :-/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle. I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but this is a good example of drag and drop capabilities. I can't comment, and I am not quite sure what you are asking. But best of luck to you!

http://jsfiddle.net/cuhuak/4CHDZ/

```
function FieldType(typeName, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.TypeName = ko.observable(typeName || "");
    self.Name = ko.observable(name || this.TypeName());
    self.createField = function () {
        return new Field(
            {
                Name: this.Name(),
                TypeName: this.TypeName()
            }
        );
    }
    self.onDragStart = function(event, ui) {
        dropFieldType  = ko.utils.domData.get(this, "ko_drag_data");
    };
    self.onDragStop = function(event, ui) {
        dropFieldType = null;
    };
}
```